# Where do I apply for a UK transit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, transit

Everyone is so helpful with informing me that I need one but no one can tell me where to apply. The uk.gov website also doesn't seem to be able to help on that front.

Answer (score 1):

On the very first page of [www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa), click on the link highlighted below, and then follow the step-by-step wizard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed a lot of pages that try to let you determine whether you need a visa, but at some point you probably end up, like I just did, [finding a page (for a standard visitor visa in my case)](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply) with an `apply` section and it seems a clear enough process.